# Smart Card Interface data units mismatch

Tags: smartcard, winscard

I'm writing code which reads data form Student ID card.
After card initialization, selecting directory and file on card I start reading data form it with READ BINARY (B0).

According to [ISO 7816-4: Interindustry Commands for Interchange](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_6_basic_interindustry_commands.aspx):

> If bit8=0 in P1, then P1||P2 is the offset of the first byte to be read in **data units** from the beginning of the file.

I'm reading data in chunks, each 16 bytes. In first loop I would like to read `offset = 0` so I set `P1 = 0x00` and `P2 = 0x00` and everything works fine, first 16 bytes are transmitted form card.

Problems start at second loop, next 16 bytes should be read from `offset = 16` so I set `P1 = 0x00` and `P2 = 0x10` but I receive data from `offset = 64`.

After some testing I've found that `P1||P2` is always interpreted as offset in 4 bytes.

It seems like my card is using **data units** (mentioned ISO 7816-4) in size of DWORD each.

All examples in Web treat **data units** as byte and everything seems to work for author/users. My question is: How can I determine the size of **data unit**  during application runtime?

Comment: Which card are you using? MPCOS? It is always better to check particular card documentation. Unfortunately a lot of cards work differently than ISO 7816 defines. Good luck!

Comment: you can evaluate the response from the file select with option to return FCI/FCP/FMD and have a look if there is any clue there